# Download the image from the urlencoded or base64encoded string

Tags: php

My application sends urlencoded or base64encoded string via http get request, the string contain image data, that most be download from the php file, but i dont know how php would download image from my string that is either  urlencoded or base64encoded, please help me out guys... im lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Serve image to a user

```
// we assume $imageData is PNG
$image = urldecode($imageData);
// or
$image = base64_decode($imageData);

// in case of force download change Content-Type: image/png to
// application/octet-stream and Content-Disposition: inline to attachment
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . md5($image) . '.png');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image));

echo $image;
exit;
```

The problem si to detect correct Content-Type if you don't know it. But browsers should be able to autodetect it on its own.

**Some notes about caching**
PHP implicitly sends headers which prevents browser caching of retrieved data. I suggest you to set these headers manually (Cache-Control, Expires, Pragma). To work properly, every single image must be served by an unique URL. Also try to avoid of starting sessions. On heavily accessed website with public access you can easily flood webserver with redundant session files.

### Save image to a file

```
$image = urlencode($imageData);
// or
$image = base64_decode($imageData);

if (!file_put_contents('abs/path/to/save/file.png', $image)) {
    throw new Exception('Image could not be saved');
}
```

Comment: let say i'm sure, that im going use urlencoded string and also sure it going be png, should i add header('Content-type: image/png');?

Comment: @user1417815 yes, and also update Content-Disposition header which is used to name the file in case user downloads it manually.

Comment: can you add the last part to your code, just to see how you place it??

Comment: @user1417815 added and also wrote down some notes about caching. Generally it's a bit difficult to properly emulate native behaviour of HTTP server via script. I was dealing with image serving for years and finally gave up in favor of simple thumbnail generator which triggers in template when `<img>` tag with generated path is echoed. But depends on your use case.

Comment: I wrote a C++ socket based http request that sends simple encoded strings in many format, after reading the raw image data, i just wanted to sends the pngs images over to my website by using php and save them there. Thanks a lot my friend! :)

Comment: But the code look to display the image, while im there does: 
$savefile = fopen('image.png', 'w');

fwrite($savefile, $contents);

fclose($savefile);
do the trick?

Comment: @user1417815 I was quite unsure from your question what do you plan to do with downloaded image. You can save it (but use rather `file_put_contents('filename', $image)`), send it to user to view (my code) or send it to user to download (change `inline` to `attachment` in Content-Disposition header).

Comment: can you please update your code? just to see how to place it right